# Typesafe: Read array of configs

Tags: scala, config, configuration-files, typesafe, typesafe-config

My `tasks.conf` file looks like below

```
tasks = [
  {
    prop_1 = "string-1"
    prop_2 = "string-2"
    prop_3 = 3
  },

  {
    prop_1 = "string-1"
    prop_2 = "string-2"
    prop_3 = 3
  }
]
```

After successfully parsing the `task.conf` file (located outside jar / classpath) using `val config: Config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(file)`, I've tried reading it as follows without success

- `config.getObjectList("tasks")`
- `config.getConfigList("tasks")`

It complains

> ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key
>   'tasks'

Upon asserting whether or not the path exists using `config.hasPath("tasks")`, it returns false.

My queries are as follows:

- Is the structure of my `conf` file correct? Even if it's correct, is there a better way to structure it?
- If the structure of `conf` file is correct (since `parseFile` succeeds), then where am I going wrong in reading the file?

Comment: Did you check if you file exists with a call to ```file.exists``` ?

Comment: You file cannot be read and this is why you get the ```missing : no configuration ... ```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your config file could not be read! Your application is probably trying to read the default application.conf, and your tasks config key is not found there.

You could probably try:

```
ConfigSource.FromFile(path)
```

Use the complete absolute path and give it a try!